# Is it possible to get the start and end points in the buffer in which text is pasted?

Tags: copy-paste, point

Like if you have a buffer containing `hel!` and paste in `lo world` after the third letter you get 4 and 11 respectively?

Emacs has many state variables, are there any that could help me in this case?

Comment: Could perhaps read point before a paste command and then count the letters in whatever is pasted. The end would be start point + paste text length. Still hard though.

Comment: You can read `(point)`, paste and then read `(point)` again.

Comment: So after paste you always end up at the end of a paste? Will test...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are just point and mark right after the yank command. Just see the doc for `yank` or `yank-pop`. If you want to conserve these positions you could advice yank. Make sure that you save these values as markers or in buffer-local variables!

One more thing: If you want to see these values just once you can call <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(mark)` and <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(point)` right after the yank command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick snippet I came up with that does what you need on brief testing.

```el
(defun my/get-yanked-text-boundaries ()
  "Yank and return the start and end boundaries of the yanked text in the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (point))
        end)
    (call-interactively #'yank)
    (setq end (point))
    (message (format "Start: %0d End: %0d" start end))
    (list start end)))
```

Comment: this works but is not the idiomatic way to do it, see Tobias' answer

Comment: JosephGarvin: That's a very good point. Thanks @Tobias.